# Udev rule to allow known USB devices won't detect my hubs

Tags: udev

I added a udev rule that would only allow known USB devices, but it just won't authorize my hubs, so every USB port is unauthorized. 
Yhis is my udev rule for the hub:

```
# Skeep not USB
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="usb_end"
# Skeep remove actions
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="usb_end"

    # 2.0 root hub
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{product}=="EHCI Host Controller", ATTR{serial}=="0000:00:1a.0", \
      ATTR{idVendor}=="1d6b", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="09", ATTR{authorized}="1", GOTO="usb_end"
    # Disable all other USB devices
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{authorized}="0"
    
    LABEL="usb_end"
```

OS: Gentoo Hardened

Kernel: 4.7.9-hardened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can debug the udev rule by setting the udev rule to execute a script. The script can log a variety of items.

for example: $DEVNAME, $ACTION

after logging all of the data out of the usb hub you'll be able to see what device is missing, or what info is missing.

udev rule, will need RUN+="/usr/local/bin/log.sh"

in the log.sh, env >> /tmp/blabla.log, or echo "$DEVNAME $ACTION ..." >> /tmp/blabla.log

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but the hub doesnt execute the script, but adding the RUN+="" to the rule for my usb stick and commenting out the ATHORIZE=0 then my usb triggers the script, but the hub doesnt

Comment: strip out all filters whilst testing just leave subsystem and run. Also check dmesg for device attibutes / ids.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm just seeing the same issue with xenial